# How to convert data in document using split-Python

Tags: python

`list.txt` document contain data like

> a,b,c,d,e,f

I want to insert above data into list or convert it as list. I tried this code. But it's not correct.

```
document=open("list.txt","r")
Mylist=[document.read().split(",")]
print(Mylist)
document.close()
```

Comment: try `Mylist=document.read().strip().split(",")` or `csv` module if you have multi-line

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Mylist=document.read().split(",") (no square brackets) will work

Comment: Thank you Jean.. It work for me.

Comment: Why do you add `[]`? `split` returns a list only.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("list.txt", "r") as Document:
    print(Document.read().split(","))
```

Comment: Great... Thank you